# Workflow 4 runtime compiling

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

In WF 4, is there a way to compile XAML at runtime?

In WF 3.5 you were able to do this via WorkflowCompiler

Is there something similar in WF 4?

Comment: You don't actually mean compile right? You mean load and run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact load an run XAML at runtime. Here are a couple links. But let's be clear that it's not compiling it -- it's interpreting it -- because that's how XAML works.

- [Walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41965/Using-WF4-WorkflowInvoker)
- [Video by Ron Jacobs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Workflow-TV/endpointtv-Lab-Introduction-to-WF4-Exercise-4-Dynamic-Workflows-with-XAML)

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: is there a way to compile it. We are using the ActivityXamlServices.Load already to load the XAML. Wondering if there is a way to compile the XAML....

Comment: No, but then again even when XAML is "Compiled" or more correctly stored in an assembly even in that case ActivityXamlServices is called to load the XAML from a stream.  In .NET 4.5 expressions are pre-compiled to improve performance in some cases.

Comment: @ronjacobs Ron is right on here, and I guess I just don't understand what you mean by compile. XAML is an efficient runtime interpreted markup language. If you're indicating that you would like to generate the corresponding Api statements for the XAML -- then I'm unaware of a tool for that -- but what is the requirement that's pushing that anyway?

Comment: we had some performance issue with loading the xaml with ActivityXamlServices and then using workflowinvoker.invoke .... so figured that if we compile the workflow into a dll then loaded by reflection that it would give better performance. Anyway we went with caching of the DynamicActivity instead it its working fine

Comment: That was a great workaround! Great job innovating. And I think @RonJacobs would be interested in hearing about your performance issues considering his position in Microsoft -- can you further expand on that?