# Should I reuse a workflow definition?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

We have a web application that has to execute tens or hundreds of workflows in a given time. After many hours spent we know that the performance bottleneck is the deserialising of workflows (we keep the xaml in the database):

```
ActivityXamlServices.Load(xamlReader, activityXamlServicesSettings);
```

So we are thinking to cache the workflows (the generated Activity objects returned by the Load method). This seems to improve the performance quite a bit. The only possible problem I can see is that the activities (from the workflow definition/tree) will be reused between workflow instances. So if an activity has the state changed in one instance it could change the behaviour of another running instance.

Note: the workflow variables don't seem to be shared between workflow instances.

EDIT: Something similar was asked: [Workflow 4 runtime compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417102/workflow-4-runtime-compiling) . The question owner seems to have arrived at the same solution of "caching of the DynamicActivity" (the activity returned by the Load method).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely reuse the dynamic activity object you get back from the de-serialized XAML as many times as you wish. You can spin up as many WorkflowApplication objects using it as you please.

**{edit}**

The activity object you get from deserializing a XAML document is just a blueprint of your workflow. It contains no state information, and so can be re-used as many times as you wish for creating `WorkflowApplication` instances from (or even the `WorkflowInvoker` utility class).

**{endEdit}**

Comment: While this caching seems to work fine so far in our system we want to make there are no edge cases problems. My concern is that Activity objects (created when workflow is loaded) are reused between workflow instances and if the activity has state then this could be a problem (one instance could alter the behaviour of another).

Comment: The activity object you get from deserializing a XAML document is just a blueprint of your workflow. It contains no "state" information of a running workflow. So you'll be fine caching that activity object for repeated use. I'll update my answer to reflect this little bit of info.

Comment: I haven't seen any mentioning of being a blueprint in official WF documentation site. Do you have any code or official docs links? What I observed using logging in my custom activities is that it sometimes creates new objects of my custom activities but sometimes it reuses them for different workflow instances. I feel there is a pattern but still investigating.